# Removing specific chunks from std::vector using a lambda function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, lambda

EDIT: Sorry, i didn't put any result. I expected to remove the (10th, 11th), then the (20th, 21st), then the (30th, 31st) and so forth but instead I get this https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI0oo.jpg

I have a vector composed by several vectors of the same size and i want to get rid of part of their end using *remove if* and a *lambda function* but there seems to be a displacement in the removal. Here is the code that I am running:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <typeinfo>


int main()
{
   int sizeOfSpectrum=10;
   int desiredSizeOfSpectrum=8;
   int count=-1;
   std::vector<int> v(100);
   std::iota (std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);
   auto newend=std::remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[&](int i)->bool{
                   count++;
                   int temp=count%sizeOfSpectrum;
                   bool test=(temp) > desiredSizeOfSpectrum;
                   return ( test);
               });
   v.erase(newend, v.end());
   std::cout << "\n";
   std::cout << "v[i]: \n";
   for(int i : v)std::cout <<v[i]<<": ";
   std::cout << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the expected output and what is it that you get ? how much displacement are we talking about here ?

Comment: Let's say i have a vector of size 100 composed by sets of data with a size 10 (so 10 sets). I wish to remove the 9th and 10th element of each set. But as you can see it removes the 10th and 11th then 10th and 22nd instead of 20th and 21st as I expected, I don't know what's happening here. http://imgur.com/TbVmLo4

Comment: And what happens instead ? What's the output that you print ?

Comment: I print what's on the screenshot

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line:

```
for(int i : v)std::cout <<v[i]<<": ";
```

When this line runs, `i` is given the value of the *contents* of each element of the vector. You are treating this as an *index* into the vector, rather than the value.

Instead use:

```
for(int i : v)
   std::cout <<i<<": ";
```

Note: you still won't get quite the output you are after, but this should give you enough to work that out for yourself.

Comment: thanks a lot, i didn't expect the problem to be from the print function at all.